# Is it possible to debug my app with adhoc provisioning profile in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

As you know, I set the Signing debug profile to Adhoc provisioning profile.

If I run my app to my iPhone, so I can use my iPhone to receive my back-stage's remote push notification.(My back-stage is using distribution profile, so I must use the adhoc or distribution profile).

But everytime I run the app(using Adhoc provisioning profile) to my iPhone, it will unconnect:

> Could not launch "project name"
>   process launch failed: failed to get the task for process xxx

So, I can not debug my app (using Adhoc provisioning profile) with real device  in my Xcode, is there any way to do that?

My requirement is go to a special `vc`, my code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is the below:

```
// If application is launched due to  notification,present another view controller.
UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if (notification)
{
    [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"success"]];

    PushDetailViewController *detail_push = [[PushDetailViewController alloc] init];
    detail_push.isPresentCome = YES;

    PushModel *new_model = [PushModel initPushModelWithDic:notification.userInfo];

    if (new_model) {

        detail_push.pushModel = new_model;

        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:detail_push animated:NO completion:nil];

    }

}else {

    //LMLSystemAlertControllerShowSingelButtonWithMessageWL(@"没有notification 信息", @"确定");
}

return YES;
```

And I don't know the `notification.userInfo` is what, so I want debug it, and if I use `SVProgressHUD` to alert out the info, my app will crash, because my iphone is unconnected with Xcode, I can not get the error info.

So, there is some questions:

1. Is it possible to debug my app(using adhoc provisioning profile) with my iphone in Xcode?
2. `notification.userInfo`'s content is what, does it is my push content from my back-state?
3. My push content(from my back-state) is where?

---

**Attempt - 1**

I tried to alert the `notification.userInfo`, but if I access the `notification.userInfo`, my app will crash, so I can not get it, do not know what it is.

**Attempt - 2**

I also use Xcode -> Deveice to find the NSLog info, find nothing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Debugging the UserInfo:
Put the NSLOG for printing UserInfo and check whether the values are coming correctly. I know you cannot check the NSLOG in Xcode console but you can check the NSLOG in Devices option in Xcode.
Xcode -> Window -> Devices -> In the left panel choose your device. Here you can see all your logs.

Based on the UserInfo details you can validate your code is correct or not.

Comment: if I `NSLog` the userinfo, could I see the log info in the Device log? I only see the stack information.

Comment: Yes you can see the NSLOG details in Device log.  Once you select the device in left panel you will wee 2 options device information and installed apps. Below that there is an arrow pointing to upper, if you select that arrow you will all the NSLOG details.

Comment: Could you Please share the screenshot where you are seeing?

Comment: see my Attempt -2.

Comment: I think you are checking device logs option. Don't check there. There will be "Arrow button in bottom left corner". Please check there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132883/discussion-between-yogesh-mv-and-aircraft).

Comment: I saw that, do you mean the device console? and if is, could only show my specified app's console?

Comment: It will show all the NSLOGS running in device. Have you checked in the log?

Comment: I test your answer, I disconnect my iphone and connect again. I can see the logs in the device. it is correct, thank you, your answer is the best adaptable.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging Push notification payload in Adhoc build mode, you can simply put `UIAlertView` where you want. And can see output on your iPhone screen. :)

**For example in your case.**

```
NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if (notification)
    {
        NSDictionary *apsInfo = [notification objectForKey:@"aps"];
        // Put AlertView here
        UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"NotificationPayload"
        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",apsInfo]
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
        otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"success"]];

        PushDetailViewController *detail_push = [[PushDetailViewController alloc] init];
        detail_push.isPresentCome = YES;
        PushModel *new_model = [PushModel initPushModelWithDic:apsInfo];

        if (new_model) {
            detail_push.pushModel = new_model;
            [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:detail_push animated:NO completion:nil];
        }

    }
    else {
         //LMLSystemAlertControllerShowSingelButtonWithMessageWL(@"没有notification 信息", @"确定");
}

return YES;
```

**Don't forget to comment or remove this AlertView code when you have done debugging.**

Comment: @M Zubair Shamshad, as a matter of fact，before you answer the question I have tested this, I tried to alert the `notification.userInfo`, but my app will crash do like this.  If I get `notification.userInfo`, my app will crash.

Comment: change your first line from `UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];` to `NSDictionary * notification =[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];`

Comment: @M Zubair Shamshad  `UILocalNotification`  ? , to what?

Comment: change `UILocalNotification` to `NSDictionary`

Comment: @M Zubair Shamshad, ok, I am doing.

Comment: @M Zubair Shamshad, I test your updated answer, it is useful, so update it, thank you, I think the Yogesh Mv's answer is the best fit my question , so I choosed his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your issue properly, but it sounds like you're having issues testing push notifications because you're using a "Production" push certificate and therefore trying to debug using an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile in order to receive the notifications?

If this is the case, then the solution is to update your push certificate.  We are no longer required to use one certificate for "Sandbox" and another for "Production" - new push certificates are valid in both environments. You should therefore be able to build and debug your app normally in Xcode using a development profile, and still receive your notifications.

[image: Now in "Sandbox and Production"]

Comment: thanks your answer, and I use our javer's back-state to push, it is use the distribution profile. your (Sandbox & Production) file means set to my app with Xcode or set to our javer's back-state?

Comment: sorry bro. I tested, I re-update the Apple Push Notification service SSL(Sandbox & Production) , I use development profile, did not receive the push info.

Comment: this will not work as only those builds that use `Development provisioning profile` are debuggable with Xcode. `Development provisioning profile` based on `Development certificate`, not `Production certificate` where push notifications are set. So you either can receive push notifications and cannot debug (`AdHoc` or `Enterprise` provisioning profiles) or you can debug but will not receive push notifications (`Development provisioning profile`)